# Copy a file using WebHDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

Is there a way to copy a file from (let's say) `hdfs://old` to `hdfs://new` without first downloading the file and then uploading it again?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for WebHDFS option?

Comment: @daemon12 yea, if don't find any other way, might go with using `hdfs` executable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about WebHDFS, but this is achievable using [hadoop distcp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html).
The command looks something like this:

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://old_nn:8020/old/location/path.file hdfs://new_nn:8020/new/location/path.file
```

Comment: Thanks @daemon12, yea, you can do it using command line

   `hdfs dfs -cp /old/location/path.file /new/location/path.file`

Comment: Oh, was it for the same HDFS instance? I thought it's for remote hdfs copy for which `distcp` is used.