# How to use webhdfs rest api to copy a file and store it in the another directory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to use httpfs to copy a file in to another directory in hdfs. for example, I can use (http://1.12.134.1234:2020/webhdfs/v1/user/xx/x?op=create&user=hello) to create a file.   I did not find in https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#File_and_Directory_Operations

Answer (score 0):

There is no webhdfs 'copy'command. Use hadoop distcp command (or retrieve contents, create new file, write the contents if the file is expected to be a smallish one). [Copy a file using WebHDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445154/copy-a-file-using-webhdfs) also answers the question.